# start-process powershell to run another powershell to run another programs with arguments. Don't works with args, but works with args

Tags: powershell

Sorry if the title seems wierd, I didn't know how to formulate this.

I'm trying to run my script in a new instance of PowerShell to run OpenVPN in the background, but I'm not able to pass any parameters to OpenVPN when called from start-process.

```
function ConnectOpenVPN{

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
  [string] $ip,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
  [string] $user
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
  [string] $pass
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
  [string] $id    

  $temp = New-TemporaryFile
  $credentials =  $user + "`n"  + $pass
  $credentials| Set-Content $temp  
  $config = "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\config\" + $id + ".ovpn"
  $file = $temp.FullName


  Start-Process powershell -args "& C:\'Program Files'\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe --config $config --auth-user-pass $file"

  #delete temp file
}
```

When I run the script with `--config $config --auth-user-pass $file` it doesn't work, but when I run the same script without these parameters everything works fine.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: As written, this script can't work because you are missing the `-FilePath` mandatory parameter on `Start-Process`. And why are you using `Start-Process` instead of directly invoking the executable e.g. `& 'C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe' --config $config --auth-user-pass $file`. It's much simpler.

Comment: It's much simplier for sure, but the script will stuck at this part I want to run the openvpn in another powershell or CMD process.

Comment: * It's much simplier for sure, but the script will stuck at this part so that's why I want to run the openvpn in another powershell or CMD process. I'm able to achieve this I wll add a parameter to the powershell process to run hidden. This function is a part of a bigger script so it can't stop at this function.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to run in PowerShell/cmd.exe rather than directly executing the program? Direct execution would look something like `$pid = Start-Process  -WindowStyle Hidden -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe' -args "--config ""$config"" --auth-user-pass ""$file"""`. Note the escaped quotes around the substituted values.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your new PowerShell window, it has a completely different scope than the one you are running the command in. This new scope has no knowledge of your $config and $file variables, so it fails when you use them because you are passing blank parameters.

To resolve this, you need to interpolate your variables prior to passing them to the -args parameter so they occur within the scope of start-process.

```
function ConnectOpenVPN{

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
[string] $ip,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
[string] $user
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
[string] $pass
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
[string] $id    

$temp = New-TemporaryFile
$credentials =  $user + "`n"  + $pass
$credentials| Set-Content $temp  
$config = "C:\'Program Files (x86)'\OpenVPN\config\" + $id + ".ovpn"
$file = $temp.FullName
$openVPN = "c:\'program files'\openvpn\bin\openvpn.exe"
$cmd = "& $openVPN --config $config --auth-user-pass $file"

Start-Process powershell.exe -args $cmd

#delete temp file
}
```

Additionally, you will want to review your quotes around $file and $config as at least the latter contains spaces.

Comment: Actually on second thought, I suspect that your problem was wholly the space in your $config path, and that the variable interpolation was in fact working but the path to the config could not be found due to the space. I'll leave this hear though as I do think it's a slightly tidier solution to pass one variable than several.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.
Note how you pass a command with arguments - to `Start-Process` and to the `&` function.

```
function ConnectOpenVPN{

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
  [string] $ip,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
  [string] $user
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
  [string] $pass
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
  [string] $id    

  $temp = New-TemporaryFile
  $credentials =  $user + "`n"  + $pass
  $credentials| Set-Content $temp  
  $config = "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\config\" + $id + ".ovpn"
  $file = $temp.FullName

  Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList @("-command", "& 'C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe' '--config' $config '--auth-user-pass' $file")

  #delete temp file
}
```